# Do I pay taxes on my SSI benefits

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security

I receive $705 per month on SSI  and LTD $456 per month total for the year is $13800 do I have to file tax returns?

Answer (score 1):

Although *Supplemental* Security Income (SSI) payments are administered by the *Social* Security Administration (SSA) they are not actually social security benefits, and are **not taxable**. See https://www.irs.gov/faqs/social-security-income/regular-disability-benefits/regular-disability-benefits (which is primarily about social security benefits, but mentions SSI as excluded).

Payment from disability insurance *funded by your employer* is taxable -- if you are below retirement age it is considered a (partial) substitute for the wages you would have earned -- but (assuming no other taxable income) $5472/year was below the filing threshhold for 2014 except for married filing separately (and even further below in 2019 when I write this).